# What is the purpose of Present Perfect in the phrase "Houston, we've had a problem"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect

I learned that the popular cliché phrase *"Houston, we have a problem."* actually sounded as:

> 055:55:35 Lovell: Ah, **Houston, we've had a problem.** We've had a Main B Bus Undervolt.

I am curious what is the purpose of using *Present Perfect* in the original phrase (and not, let's say, Past Simple)?

Comment: I'm just speculating, but it might not even be a question of purpose. When speaking, it's very common to start saying something one way, then switch mid-sentence to a different wording, and end up with an overall wording that you wouldn't have used if you had thought it all through in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the original quotation "Houston, we've had a problem" is often misquoted as "Houston, we *have* a problem". In fact, for the 1995 movie 'Apollo 13' the line was deliberately changed to "*have*".

A problem is something that requires a *solution*, so it can be spoken of as something *ongoing* if it is unsolved, or in the past tense if it is over.

- I had a problem earlier but I solved it.
- I have a problem that needs solving.

It would have made more sense for Jim Lovell to say to Houston ground control that they "*have*" a problem, as it was ongoing - but given the extremely precarious situation they were in, I think we can forgive him for not using perfect grammar under the circumstances.